# Signature and Date strip not aligning

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a signature and date aligned on a certificate I've created in HTML (but will be printed out).

As it currently stands, the fields all collapse onto multiple lines, and I want them all on the same line, like this:

[image: Concept]

And here's the code:

```css
.sign {font-weight:bold;}
.sign span {width:7cm;border-bottom:0.1em solid #000;display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="sign">
    Signature:<span></span>Date:<span></span>(dd mon yyyy)
</div>
```

I know the solution is simple I just can't think straight at the moment!

Comment: .sign span {width:200px;border-bottom:0.1em solid #000;display:inline; margin:0 15px}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `display:inline-block` instead of `block`. `inline-block` makes it easy to keep on the same line.

```css
.sign {font-weight:bold;}
.sign span {width:3cm;border-bottom:0.1em solid #000;display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="sign">
    Signature:<span></span>Date:<span></span>(dd mon yyyy)
</div>
```

(note that i shrunk it to 3cm for this example so that it fits in the snippet)

Comment: Thanks dude, I'll accept the answer when the time limit runs out :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `inline-block` for the `display` property instead of `block`.

Comment: Thanks dude, you were beat to it though

Answer (score 1):

You just have to display them `inline-block` I have added the margin to create the desired result

```css
.sign {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.sign span {
  width: 4cm;
  border-bottom: 0.1em solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sign">
  Signature:<span></span>Date:<span></span>(dd mon yyyy)
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks dude, you were just beaten to it though :)

Answer (score 1):

**Html**

```
<div class="sign">
  Signature: <span></span> Date: <span></span>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.sign {
  font-wight: bold;
}
.sign span {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s53q3e61/)